# How does this "Generate Bezier" function works?

Tags: graphics, curve-fitting, bezier

I'm reading the code for GraphicsGem's implementation for fitting cubic bezier curves [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200506155155/http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Egraphics/books/GraphicsGems/gems/FitCurves.c). I understand most of the code but I'm having trouble understanding the function called "Generate Bezier", which from my current knowledge, takes the points on which we are fitting the curve, their parameterizations and tangent vectors at both ends of the curve and spits out a cubic bezier curve. However, how the function *itself* works I have no clue. Any help is appreciated.

I know it has something to do with the least-squares method from the comment but still.

Comment: If you don't understand code, show the code in your post (in addition to the link you currently have). However, also remember to properly format it, which is very much not the case for the code you've linked to. And of course also bear in mind that after properly formatting the code, it might be a lot easier to read, so see if you understand what the documentation says happens after a formatting pass. And if you don't, at least you'll now be able to explain which exact lines that you're showing in your post are hard to understand.